# Заполнение двумерного массива С

Tags: c, массивы, генерация-случайных-данных

Нужно заполнить двумерный массив случайными значениями от 0 до 9, но возникает ошибка. Помогите, как это исправить?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define R 2
#define C 4
 
int main(void)
{
  int arr[R][C];
 
  for (int i = 0; i < R; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < C; ++j) {
        arr[i] = rand() % 9;
        arr[j] = rand() % 9;
        printf("arr[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, arr[i][j]);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

# include <time.h>

#define R 2
#define C 4
 
int main(void)
{

  // чтобы не было одинаковых случайных чисел всегда
  srand(time(NULL));

  int arr[R][C];
 
  for (int i = 0; i < R; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < C; ++j) {

        // % - это остаток от деления
        // % 10 - даст числа от 0 до 9
        arr[i][j] = rand() % 10;

        printf("arr[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, arr[i][j]);
    }
  return 0;
}
```